# path errors in python executable through command

Tags: python, path, pyinstaller, executable

i have been stuck on this problem for a couple of weeks now, i feel i am going around in circles.

i am trying to make a standalone python executable app on my desktop, i have been through the installing pyinstaller, however its not recognised despite installing it numerous times, i have the path for it and added it to my system variables and also my personal variables on the path but i just cant seem to get my command prompt to recognise that i have done this. i am a beginner so please be kind to me.

Comment: To confirm, you are restarting your command prompt between adding it to your system variables right? What did you use to install pyinstaller? If you used pip you can do `pip list` to see what packages it has registered as installed and check for pyinstaller.

Comment: hi, i am restarting it each time, i used; "pip install pyinstaller", if it helps i am using thonny to write all this, i have saved the thonny script to my desktop. thank you, i used your pip list and got this; "pyinstaller               5.8.0
pyinstaller-hooks-contrib 2022.14".

Comment: uninstalled then installed pyinstaller which seemed to work, now have dist folder for .exe app however when i click it it wont load, event viewer shows; "The program or feature "\??\C:\Users\G4GAZ\Desktop\Argents_helper_app\Argents_helper_app.exe" cannot start or run due to incompatibity with 64-bit versions of Windows. Please contact the software vendor to ask if a 64-bit Windows compatible version is available." how do i get around this. thank you